# Exponential Fit of n points

Tags: c#, .net, data-fitting, mathnet-numerics

I have n points (up to 513 points) that I need to fit in

```
y = y0 + a*exp(b*x)
```

I have been using `MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Exponential`, but the problem is coeficient `y0`, or when I have negative Y points, the result is

```
(NaN, NaN)
```

Example Points just first 7 points

```
double[] x = {0.000311999989207834, 0.00033149998853332363, 0.00035099998785881326, 0.0003704999871843029, 0.0003899999865097925, 0.00040949998583528213, 0.00042899998516077176};
double[] y = {-1.414255976676941, -1.415171504020691, -1.406565546989441, -1.3984631299972534, -1.398417353630066, -1.4013928174972534, -1.4019421339035034};
Tuple<double, double> t1 = Fit.Exponential(x, y);
```

Also I tried to find the lowest Y point and then substract from all points, but I think its not proper way to do it.

Reference photo (what I want to get): Graph of points and fit
[image: Graph of points and fit]

Comment: Adding a constant to the data, when fitted by a function including a constant, is absolutely no problem and legit.

Answer (score 0):

A non-iterative method of fitting which doesn't requires initial guess of parameters is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

With your simplified example the calculus and result are shown below.

[image]

[image]

If some specific criteria of fitting is specified you can use the above results as initial values of parameters in a software for iterative method of fitting.